# CMS shortcode in product page

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, product-page

I am using Ultimo theme for my website and I want to use their featured product slider shortcode in product pages.

```
{{block type="ultimo/product_list_featured" template="catalog/product/list_featured_slider.phtml" category_id="4" product_count="8" size="size-xs" is_random="1" block_name="Random Products"}}
```

I can get the shortcode work by doing adding it from `layout.xml` and calling the block from view.phtml, what I couldn't do or don't know how to assign the `category_id, product_count, is_random` parts to the `layout.xml` or in `view.phtml` while calling the block.

I want to assign the category_id with the current product's category id and set the number of products in the slider, also the slider products must come randomly with each page refresh. `(product_count and is_random can be set via layout.xml)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get category from `registry` and call the `phtml` grammatically

```
<?php $catid = Mage::registry('current_category') ? Mage::registry('current_category')->getId() : null;
  echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('ultimo/product_list_featured')->setCategoryId($catid)->setProductCount(8)->setSize('size-xs')->setIsRandom(1)->setTemplate('catalog/product/list_featured_slider.phtml')->toHtml();
?>
```